# JavaScript Scrolling Images

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript so go easy. I am trying to create a section of a web page to highlight a company's clients. Rather than list them all, I would like to create a auto scrolling effect. For instance, upon landing on the page a visitor sees two logos in the "clients" section, and two seconds later, that area auto displays two new logos.

Can anyone point me to a good source to implement this?

I hope that makes sense. I will be looking for an example in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to build off an existing framework and then use a plugin to provide the scrolling. I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) a lot, so I would recommend jQuery and a plugin like one of the following:

1. [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/)
2. [jQuery Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)